# Verilog combined assignemnts

Tags: verilog, assignment-operator

Hi in Verilog what is the significance of this operation:

```
wire signal_A = |signal_B;
```

Is this possible with other logic operators?

Comment: It is a reduction OR: It OR-es all bit of B together. Thus A is high if at least one bit in B is high, A is low if all bits of B are low. Yes, you can use & or ^ too.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a short-cut for

```
wire signal_A;
assign  signal_A = |signal_B;
```

IMHO, Verilog is full of unnecessary shortcuts making it more difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been more explicit in the question.

But the answer is that this is used for logic on 2 varying width signals

```
wire signal_A;
wire [N:0] signal_B;

assign signal_A = |signal_B;
```

This is equivalent to

```
assign signal_A = signal_B[0] | ... | signal_B[N];
```

So not as verbose and explicit as VHDL, but quicker.